# Execute command after the completion of Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to execute a command after execution of a shell script. 
Following code is what i have tried so far:

```
#! /bin/bash
exec >> /tmp/foo.log

#$REPO and $AUTHOR are environmental varibles
echo "test" >> /tmp/foo.log
echo $REPO >> /tmp/foo.log
echo $AUTHOR >> /tmp/foo.log

exit 0

cd /var/www/html/websvn
php remove_commits.php $REPO $AUTHOR
```

The above script is not working for some reason. How can i fix this? Need your help badly.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the exec statement at the top? You haven't told it what to execute. In addition, when you run exit 0, the shell will exit; later commands will not be run.

Comment: @Saposhiente in this case, "cat >> /tmp/foo.log" is not for execution for some program. it redirects all stdout to /tmp/foo.log. so other three ">>/tmp/foo.log" is not needed.

Comment: (The `cat` in the preceding comment should obviously be `exec`.)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to execute the cd command and the php script, you will need to remove the exit 0.  That exits the script.

Comment: How do I execute cd command and the php script after successful execution of commands above it? Do i need to create another shell script and add cd command and the php script?

Comment: As sophishiente pointed out, check out the exec >> /tmp/foo.log.  Specifically, what do you think that is supposed to do? Hint: remove that line and see if that will fix your problem.

Comment: How do you suppose the `echo` commands could fail? Anyway, adding `set -e` to the top of the script will force it to terminate in case of error.

Comment: echo will not fail. I was referencing the odd exec >> /tmp/foo.log line.

Comment: It's not odd; see @JungsuHeo's comment.

Answer (score 0):

below code runs php after foo.sh is successful.

```
$ ./foo.sh && (cd /var/www/html/websvn; php remove_commits.php $REPO $AUTHOR)
```

**`exec >> /tmp/foo.log`** this redirect all output of following command to `/tmp/foo.log`. not for execution command. refer to http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/exec